# Submitting two forms with one function does not work

Tags: php, javascript

I am facing a problem to submit two forms with one JavaScript function.

In that I have called one ajax file to check the username availability.

The forms are as below

```
<form action="abc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return isValid(this)" class="login_form" style="width:100%;">  

<form action="http://example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return isValid(this)" class="login_form" style="width:100%;" name="form1" id="form1">
```

In isValid() function when I do

```
    alert ("hi");
    document.form1.submit();
    alert("bye");
```

Then it submitting the form1 else it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a boolean value from the `isValid()` function since you're passing that value back to the `onsubmit` event of the forms:

Something like this should work for what you need:

```
function isValid() {
    // Do my validation here.
    return true; // or return false, depending on validation results.
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `target="_blank"` attribute to the second form. It might be that your browser is preventing the submission of the forms because they relate to different files, and the browser is confused about where to redirect the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code for that,

```
    var form1 = submit1();
    document.form1.submit();

    function submit1(){
      document.form2.submit();
      return true;
    }
```

In that `submit1` function after submitting form you should `return true` then it will submit second form.